# TerraForm: deploying EC2 instances without starting them

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to deploy my infrastructure in different AWS environments (dev, prod, qa).

That deployment creates a few EC2 instances from a custom AMI. When deployed, instances are in the "running" state. [I understand this seems to be related to some constraint in the EC2 API](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html). However, I don't necessarily want my instances started, depending on context. Sometimes, I just want the instances to be created, and they will be started later on. I guess this is a quite common scenario.

Reading the few related issues/requests on Hashicorp's github, makes me think so:

- [Terraform aws instance state change](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5213)
- [Stop instances](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22)
- [aws_instance should allow to specify the instance state](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/190)

There must be some TerraForm based solution which doesn't require to rely on AWS CLI / CDK or lambda, right? Something in the TerraForm script that, for example, would stop the instance right after its creation.

My google foo didn't help me much here. Any help / suggestion for dealing with that scenario is welcome.

Comment: There is no such a solution. When instance is created it is automatically started by aws. Tf has no control overt that. You can use user data to stop the instance or local exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its all up to your use case. We don't do this generally. Still, if you want to provision your EC2 instances and need to put them in stopped state, as [bschaatsbergen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13155217/bschaatsbergen) suggested, you can use the **user_data** in Terraform. Make sure to attach the role with relevant permission.

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/`
REGION=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'`
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids $INSTANCE_ID --region $REGION
```

Answer (score 3):

Provisioning a new instance automatically puts it in a 'started' state.

As Marcin suggested, you can use user data scripts, here's some psuedo user data script. For you to figure out the actual implementation ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
get instance id, pass it to the subsequent line
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

You can read about running scripts as part of the bootstrapping here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: The problem is when volume attachments needs to happen and the boot needs to be delayed that that can happen before the user-data attempts to set up volumes on those disks... This stops them, but then the rest of the script won't run to set up that volume on the second boot.

Comment: Solid spot @GertvandenBerg

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by others, you cannot just "create" instances, they will be in "started" state.

Rather I would ask what is the exact use case here :

> Sometimes, I just want the instances to be created, and they will be started later on.

Why you have to create instances now and use them later? Can't they be created exactly when they are required? Any specific requirement to keep them initialized before they are used? Or the instances take time to start?

Comment: Unrelated to Terraform: upon startup instance runs "setup" script. This script wrecks all kinds of configuration settings if instance-specific resources (network interfaces, security groups, EFS / RDS / whatever) are not properly attached to the instance. And there is no way to create them prior to creating an instance because IP / DNS / other instance settings aren't known upon instance creation and these settings are required to setup those instance-specific resources.

Comment: Because provisioning takes longer than simply starting an instance that is already provisioned.  And before you go down the argument of using docker and K8.  Sometimes a VM instance is just what is needed and they may have their own autoscaler to spin the instance based on custom demands.

Comment: Attaching disks - if the disks is created with the instance in Terraform, later changes are ignored, so a separate `aws_volume` and `aws_volume_attachment` is needed and they should be created before the instance is started that the user-data can set that disk up...